# Delete item from MongoDB with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to delete a user id from all collections that have a reference to it. I'm bringing a user id across from the form and want to remove every reference to it in every business collection. I know the below query doesn't work but it shows my current approach.

```
db.collection('business', function (err, allBus){
    allBus.update({}, { $pull: {followers: { userID } } } );
});
```

Here is my data, any ideas?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55355d0ab063708c0b73809e"),
    "address" : "Donegal",
    "businessName" : "burkes shoes",
    "email" : "info@burkes.ie",
    "followers" : [
            ObjectId("55300f5208224af428d1beaf"),
            ObjectId("553129666252d2fc0a4634e4")
    ],
    "gpsLat" : "55.1763595",
    "gpsLong" : "-7.7923",
    "homeDomain" : "www.burkes.ie",
    "imgpath" : "\\images\\uploads\\57461Burkes_logo_1429560586607.jpg",
    "password" : "1",
    "role" : "business"
}
```

Comment: you want to delete entire record or only remove data from `"followers"`? Also match the `"_id"` field?

Comment: I want to remove only one id(userID from the form) from every instance business

Comment: i didn't understand clearly. if `id = '55355d0ab063708c0b73809e'` then what will be deleted from the `data` given  as sample. Also  for this value `55300f5208224af428d1beaf`.

Comment: you want to delete those documents  where `userID` contains in `followers` ?

Comment: Yes yogesh, exactly.

Comment: No sorry, yogesh, I misunderstood you. I only want to remove the userId from the array of followers

Comment: is your `userID` string or mongo object? you tried mongo query ?

Answer (score 1):

If `userID` is a string you will need to cast it first to ObjectID before using it in your query. Something like this should do the magic:

```
var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID,
    userID = new ObjectId("55300f5208224af428d1beaf"); 
/*
   if userID is a string then this will work 
   var userID = new ObjectId(userID);
*/
db.business.update(
    {"followers": userID}, 
    {
        "$pull": { "followers": userID }
    },
    { multi: true }
);
```

The query above will have better performance than an update without a query as it first filters documents that have in their followers array an element with the `userID` value and then updates the matched documents by pulling the `ObjectID` value from the array.